# Using MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE leading to inconsistent results based on same query of execution

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to determine why these two LOAD DATA INFILEs produce different results. Both queries below import the data.

**In the first query w/ exec the quotes are not removed from the table fields**. The second query removes the quotes as expected. I've tried all variations of the exec query - same problem... For example, I tried:

```
'\"' - (as is now)

"' . " . '"

'"' - (this of course won't work because it needs escaping \ )

'" . " . "' - (this also needs escaping)

\"\"
```

And a lot of other variations.

**Example output (in table field):**

Query 1: "Joe Smoe"

Query 2: Joe Smoe

**Am I looking at the wrong problem?** I also tried re-writing the query several times, but determined I have the query written properly.

**I am running these queries against the exact same data.** They both load the data, but the **1st query fails to remove the " (quotes)** from the string.

**Query 1**

```
exec(mysql -u root -e \"USE mydb; LOAD DATA INFILE '" . $file . "' INTO TABLE  myTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'\"; ");
```

AND

**Query 2**

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filepath' INTO TABLE myTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by doing:

```
$mysqli->query("LOAD DATA INFILE '" . $file . "' INTO TABLE  myTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");
```